# Java Spring boot hibernate delete cascade data

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, orm

I've a problem with right removing data from db.
I use Hibernate orm in my spring boot app and now is the moment when I want to delete user from db. But there're realations and some tables contain foreign keys to parent table user. How to delete all the data linked where are foreign keys?
Here are my all tables: and name of the columns with keys:

```
- User - id
- Workers - id(fk)
- Resetkeys - userId(fk)
- UserRole - userId(fk)
- Tokens - userId(fk)
```

And how delete user with all this data?
Thanks for help!

Comment: you did not say anything about your entity relationship. How did you mapped them ? what are the `cascade` policy or other stuffs ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use relation annotations in your model? 
Like this,

@OneToMany(cascade = **CascadeType.REMOVE**)

Refer to the spec https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html

Comment: I used cascade = CascadeType.ALL

Comment: I've changed it to CascadeType.REMOVE, won't work, also added on delete cascade to tables

Answer (score 0):

(**Edited**)

Without any reference to frameworks like Spring or Hibernate, you can simply set up your database tables with constraints on the foreign key columns in order to delete all related records when the "user" record is deleted. The constraint is referred to as `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and if you define it on the foreign key column of a joined table, the RDBMS will automatically delete all the records for which the foreign key matches the selected user ID of the deleted record.

Try doing some research on the `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint specifically for the database server you are using for more details.

(**Edit #2**)
Here is a **modified** example from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  category INT NOT NULL, id INT NOT NULL,
  price DECIMAL,
  PRIMARY KEY(category, id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE product_order (
  no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_category INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(no),
  INDEX (product_category, product_id),
  INDEX (customer_id),

  FOREIGN KEY (product_category, product_id)
    REFERENCES product(category, id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,

  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
    REFERENCES customer(id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The example shows a relationship between `product` and `product_order`. When deleting a record from the `product` table (just simply running `DELETE FROM product WHERE id=... and category=...`), all the referenced records in the `product_order` table will be automatically deleted without any additional SQL statements.
 On the other hand, when deleting a row from the `customer` table you will get the same error you are getting now, because the default constraint restricts delete operations on records in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you write the example queries for my data, which I've mentioned in upper code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example ;

```
 DELETE FROM progress FROM progress INNER JOIN offices ON progress.RegNo = offices.RegNo WHERE offices.ProjectID = :id;
    DELETE FROM offices WHERE offices.ProjectID = :id;
    DELETE FROM workrooms WHERE workrooms.ProjectID = :id;
```

NB: Use parameters to pass values ​​to the query instead of adding the values ​​directly to the string. If you don't, you can expose your code to SQL Injection. So you have to pay some attention.I wanted to explain the offices and rooms here by taking an example.

Answer (score -1):

what about disabling and re-enabling the foreign key constraints before and after dlete operation.

```
alter table Resetkeys nocheck constraint all
delete from Resetkeys ...
alter table Resetkeys check constraint all
```

Comment: No. Is there any operation on DELETE ?

Comment: I added names of all tables why do you use MyTable

Comment: @johnson Tables don't allow you to delete a record if they do have a foreign key constraint. What I  did  : - I disabled the check for the constraints in the table(Resetkeys ), then  after deleting a record again I turned on the constraint check. This is a sample, You can do it for all tables if you find it helpful.